# How to have information about the current visited level when doing BFS or DFS traversal iteratively?

Tags: c#, .net, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, visitor-pattern

I am thinking about creating my very own serializer and and I needed a simple way to write a property visitor for a given .NET Type in order to fetch the attributes on every property (inc nested ones).

It seems that the simplest way would be to start with a iterative version of the DFS or BFS for going through all the properties, so I started to write the code below:

```
public static class Algorithms
{
    public static IEnumerable<TNode> DfsIterativeTraverse<TNode>(this TNode node, Func<TNode, IEnumerable<TNode>> childNodeSelectors) 
    {
        if (node == null)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        var stack = new Stack<TNode>();
        stack.Push(node);

        while (stack.Any()) 
        {
            var top = stack.Pop();
            foreach (var child in childNodeSelectors(top)) 
            {
                stack.Push(child);
            }
            yield return top;
        }
    }
    public static IEnumerable<TNode> BfsIterativeTraverse<TNode>(this TNode node, Func<TNode, IEnumerable<TNode>> childNodeSelectors) 
    {
        if (node == null)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        var queue = new Queue<TNode>();
        queue.Enqueue(node);

        while (queue.Any()) 
        {
            var front = queue.Dequeue();
            foreach (var child in childNodeSelectors(front))
            {
                queue.Enqueue(child);
            }
            yield return front;
        }
    }
}
```

And then apply it to some anonymous classes to fetch the different properties:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        var stuff = new
        {
            A1 = new
            {
                B1 = new
                {
                    D1 = 42
                },
                C1 = new
                {
                    E1 = "Hello"
                }
            },
            A2 = new
            {
                B2 = new
                {
                    D2 = 42
                },
                C2 = new
                {
                    E2 = "Hello"
                }
            }
        };

        var properties = stuff.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var childProperties = property.DfsIterativeTraverse(x =>
            {
                if (x.PropertyType.IsPrimitive|| x.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                {
                    return Enumerable.Empty<PropertyInfo>();
                }

                return x.PropertyType.GetProperties();
            });

            var count = 0;
            foreach (var childProperty in childProperties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{$"\t".Repeat(count)}{childProperty.Name}: {childProperty.PropertyType.Name}");
                count++;
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Repeat(this string source, int count)
    {
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(source.Length * count);
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(source);
        }

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

But this code returns:

```
A1: <>f__AnonymousType1`2
        C1: <>f__AnonymousType3`1
                E1: String
                        B1: <>f__AnonymousType2`1
                                D1: Int32
A2: <>f__AnonymousType4`2
        C2: <>f__AnonymousType6`1
                E2: String
                        B2: <>f__AnonymousType5`1
                                D2: Int32
```

I then realized that I need information about the current level in order to have, for example Bx and Cx on the same level.

I thought about adding a count that is going to be incremented but it turns out that it is not that simple.

Comment: for my BFS SAT solver i used this function to detect if i'm on a new level or not(ShuffleNumber is inceremented each time a node is processed)

public static Boolean TimeToShuffle(int ShuffleNumber)
        {
            int cpt = 0;
            String x = Convert.ToString(ShuffleNumber, 2);
            foreach (char c in x)
                if (c.Equals('1'))
                    cpt++;
            if (cpt == 1)
                return true;

            return false;
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually pretty simple.

```
interface ILevel
{
    int Level { get; set; }
}


public static IEnumerable<TNode> DfsIterativeTraverse<TNode>(this TNode node, Func<TNode, IEnumerable<TNode>> childNodeSelectors)
    where TNode : class, ILevel
{
    if (node == null)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    var currentLevel = 0;
    node.Level = 0;

    var stack = new Stack<TNode>();
    stack.Push(node);

    while (stack.Any())
    {
        var top = stack.Pop();
        foreach (var child in childNodeSelectors(top))
        {
            child.Level = top.Level + 1;
            stack.Push(child);
        }
        yield return top;
    }
}
```

The code is not perfect, since it modifies the node, but you can refactor it in a safer way if it is needed in your case. Anyway, the problem should be solved, since now each your node should have the `Level` property with initialized value.

And the last note... I hope writing own serializer is purely educational project. Otherwise I would advise you to search for existing ones.

Comment: yup it can refactored quite a lot but I get the gist, I thought returning an IEnumerable of (value type) Tuple with (int level, TNode node). It's not only for educational purposes I found a lot of serializers lacking features about prefixes, simple attributes that have constants with just one without screwing up the business model you and loosing a bit the interest of the serialization itself, I've checked: https://github.com/wojtpl2/ExtendedXmlSerializer, https://github.com/FCBshnik/SimpleXmlSerializer, https://github.com/sinairv/YAXLib but none of them provide what I am looking for.

Comment: Of course, it's very rare when the existing solution perfectly solves the exact problem. But it's much cheaper to workaround/hack all problems in a working product then create an own from scratch. Serialization in C# is not something what can be done easily, it's a very complicated problem. Good luck!

Comment: I am fully aware, I have a working solution but it uses crappish IXmlSerializable and I am not satisfied with that solution and thought learning something new along the way. I know that serialization is tricky but learning is also part of the job. It's too bad that attribute based serialization in xml is so limited. I picked the IXmlSerialisable way so that if someone is taking over that my code, it's still easy to understand albeit a bit verbose without scewing up the business model.